# Rails use SQL group_by

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, json, activerecord

I got a model call `Answer`, and here is its table

```
id      group_id    qset_id 
1       123            1
2       123            2
3       123            1
4       456            1
5       456            1
6       456            3
```

I need to return a `array` or `json` format include every `group_id` and their different `qset_id`

Maybe like this

```
class: [
    {
        "group_id": 123
        "qset_id": [1,2]
    },
    {
        "group_id": 456
        "qset_id": [1,3]
    }
]
```

I thought about `group_by`, but I am stuck here. And the table is very large, is there a efficient Rails way to handle that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this ?

```
@answer = Answer.all.group_by(&:group_id) 

@answer.each_with_index do |answer, index|
  {
   'group_id': index,
   'qset_id: answer.flatten.map{|x| x_id}
  }    
end
```

---

```
I have to tell that I had to study more query sql to find this solution

ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query('SELECT group_id, GROUP_CONCAT(qset_id) FROM answers GROUP BY group_id').rows.to_h
```

I created a test here for this and I received the correct answer.

```
4.1.15@2.2.0 (main)> ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query('SELECT proposal_id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT unit_id) FROM bookings GROUP BY proposal_id').rows.to_h
  SQL (0.2ms)  SELECT proposal_id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT unit_id) FROM bookings GROUP BY proposal_id
=> {1=>"2,3", 3=>"4", 4=>"5", 5=>"6"}
```

Comment: I am not sure, cause it took to long and the result didn't show.  The `Answer` is very huge (more than 10 million record)

Comment: So you need to do this action directly in sql